# Get name of the element on template shown from database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm using for loop to show some data on template from models. With every loop I'm rendering a button with the elements. How can I get that particular looped element's id when the button which was rendered with it was clicked.

For example if I click on approve button in the second row, I need to get id, username, etc. from that row.

[Image for above problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kr4ZC.png)

template.html

```
{% for applications in applications  %}
    
        <div class="applicationList">
            <table style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <th>Request ID</th>
                    <th>Employee</th>
                    <th>Reason for Leave</th>
                    <th>From Date</th>
                    <th>To Date</th>
                    <th>Approve/Deny</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ applications.id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ applications.user }}</td>
                    <td>{{ applications.reason }}</td>
                    <td>{{ applications.from_date }}</td>
                    <td>{{ applications.to_date }}</td>
                    <td>
                    <form method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input class="appproveButton appproveButtonYes" type="submit" name="approve" value="Approve">
                    <input type="submit" class="appproveButton appproveButtonNo"name="deny" value="Deny">
                    </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div

    {% endfor %}
```

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='login/')
def applications_view(request):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        applications = LeaveApplication.objects.all()
        if request.method == "POST":
          pass  
        context = {
            'applications': applications
        }
        return render(request, 'home/applications.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd be best having a hidden input value in each form if this is how your page is setup.

Something like;

```html
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" id="applications_id" name="applications_id" value="{{ applications.id }}">
    <input class="appproveButton appproveButtonYes" type="submit" name="approve" value="Approve">
    <input type="submit" class="appproveButton appproveButtonNo"name="deny" value="Deny">
</form>
```

Then in python you can just do `request.POST.get('applications_id')`